# How to print a list of lists in different lines?

Tags: python, list, formatting

I'm trying to make a Pascal pyramid in python and I'm doing it with a list of lists, that way it's easier to insert the values I need it positions I need them, everything is working fine except when I print the list of lists it doesn't format correctly line by line the way I want it to

I've tried formatting with end=" ", and by using a * to unpack the list of lists however none of these seem to work

```py
    def unos(n,fila,columna,m):
        mitad=columna//2
        m[0][4]=1
        for i in range(1,fila):
            x=mitad+i
            y=mitad-i
            m[i][x]=1
            m[i][y]=1

    **print(*m)**#The error seems to be here(I could be wrong)
```

Python prints m this way: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

However what I need it printed out is this:

[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, we must inspect the unpacking operator (`*`) and how it works with `print`.

Recall that the unpacking operator takes a single iterable and turns it into multiple elements which are passed in series to a function.

Then, we know that `print` takes multiple arguments in the form of `args`, using a separator to separate them, if necessary. With this in mind, we can see that the four ways to print `a b c` are equivalent:

```
print('a', 'b', 'c')
print(*['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(sep.join(['a', 'b', 'c']))
print('a' + sep + 'b' + sep + 'c')
```

...where `sep` is, by default,  (a single space).

Now, we note that `m` is a *nested* `list`. Therefore, by doing `print(*m)`, what you are doing is effectively `print(m[0], m[1]...m[-1])`, where `m[0]`, `m[1]...m-1` are individually `lists`.

By referring to our analysis of `print` above, we can see that that is the same as `print(m[0] + ' ' + m[1] + ' ' + ... + ' ' + m[-1])`.

Clearly, there are no newlines in that, but there should be newlines where there are now spaces.

To get what we want, which is a newline after each element, therefore, we can just do `print(*m, sep='\n')`.

Comment: Thank you!, I'm only getting started with programming so this must seem like a really dumb question to ask

Comment: @JohelPF The only dumb thing is being too scared to ask and improve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.join` to show it all together in a string:

```
>>> print("\n".join("".join(str(e) for e in x) for x in l))
000010000
000101000
001000100
010000010
100000001
```

Where `l` is your `m`

Answer (score 0):

Just need individual print statements.

```
for l in m:
    print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html):

```
import pprint
stuff = ['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni']
stuff.insert(0, stuff)
pprint.pprint(stuff)
```

result :

```
 [<Recursion on list with id=...>,
 'spam',
 'eggs',
 'lumberjack',
 'knights',
 'ni']
```

you can see more examples [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)